# Sobreescritura sobre interfaz tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

Tengo este Código, al momento de llamar a la función `def sismor_funcion(self)` por medio del botón `self.boton_aceptar` me da como respuesta lo que esta dentro de la función mencionada; mi problema inicia cuando vuelvo a presionar el botón `self.boton_aceptar`, se sobreescribe sobre el resultado anterior, como lo muestro en la imagen.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

class sismicidad():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vent_sismi = tk.Tk()
        self.vent_sismi.title("SISMICIDAD")
        self.pest_sismor = ttk.Notebook(self.vent_sismi)
        self.pest_sismor.grid(row=0, column = 0)
        self.sismorresistente_1()
        self.perf_suelos()
        self.zona_sismi()
        self.sismor_funcion()
        self.vent_sismi.mainloop()

    def sismorresistente_1(self):
        ....

    def cerrar(self):
        ....

    def perf_suelos(self):
        self.pest_1 = ttk.Frame(self.pest_sismor)
        self.pest_sismor.add(self.pest_1, text = "Perfiles de suelos")
        self.eti_fra_11 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.pest_1, text="Perfiles de suelos")
        self.eti_fra_11.grid(row=0,column=0, padx=10, pady=20)
        self.eti_lab_11 = ttk.Label(self.eti_fra_11, text="Velocidad de corte Vs (m/seg):")
        self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=100, pady=10)
        self.vel_corte = tk.IntVar()
        self.entry_1 = ttk.Entry(self.eti_fra_11, textvariable = self.vel_corte)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)
        #Falta poner Boton: CALCULAR
        self.boton_aceptar = ttk.Button(self.eti_fra_11, text ="Aceptar", command = self.sismor_funcion)
        self.boton_aceptar.grid(row=2,column=0, padx=10, pady=20)

    def zona_sismi(self):
        ....

    def sismor_funcion(self):

        self.x1=self.entry_1.get()

        try:
            self.x1=int(self.x1)

        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir solo números enteros.")

        while True:
            if self.x1 > 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11 = ttk.Label(self.eti_fra_11, text="Perfil tipo S0: Roca Dura.")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0)

            elif self.x1 > 500 and self.x1 <= 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11 = ttk.Label(self.eti_fra_11, text="Perfil tipo S1: Roca y Suelos muy rigidos.")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0)

            elif self.x1 > 180 and self.x1 <= 500:
                self.eti_lab_11 = ttk.Label(self.eti_fra_11, text="Perfil tipo S2: Suelos Intermedios.")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0)

            elif self.x1 <= 180:
                self.eti_lab_11 = ttk.Label(self.eti_fra_11, text="Perfil tipo S3: Suelos Blandos.")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0)
            break

aplicacion = sismicidad()
```

Imagen del resultado, lo encerrado en rojo es lo que esta sobre escrito.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miguel, estás re-instanciando cada vez la etiqueta `self.eti_lab_11`. Por decirlo de algún modo:

Estás poniendo cada vez una nueva etiqueta con el mismo nombre, en el mismo lugar.

Cambia:

```
self.eti_lab_11 = ttk.Label(self.eti_fra_11, text="Perfil tipo S0: Roca Dura.")
```

por

```
self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S0: Roca Dura.")
```

Eso aplicado en cada caso, actualizará sólo el valor de la etiqueta que creaste inicialmente.

Comment: Esta bien, voy a evitar redundar el codigo sobre una misma etiqueta. Gracias... ahora me falta evitar ese sobreescrito que se produce al correr el codigo.

Comment: Buena!!!... esta es la respuesta...